# Check health of Docker using Python Script - Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, docker, automation, python-2.x

I want to write a python script (Python 2.7) to check the health of the Docker (using command 'docker ps').

```
docker ps
```

and it returns anything then it is healthy and exit the script. If the command is **hung for more than 2 minutes** then print "The Docker is stopped"

Kindly help me to figure out how to check whether it hung for 2 minutes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) takes an explicit `timeout` option (as of Python 3.3).

Comment: Sorry I am currently using python 2.7. is this work for python 2.7

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?